# implementation of inheritance in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

addEmployee – This method will take Employee reference as parameter and add the same to the employees list after checking if employee with same id does not exist. It will return total employees count if addition is successful, else return -1.

```
public class Employee {
    private int empId;
    private String name;
    private double basicPay;
    private double perksPay;
    public Employee()
    {

    }
    public Employee(int empId, String name, double basicPay, double perksPay) {
        super();
        this.empId = empId;
        this.name = name;
        this.basicPay = basicPay;
        this.perksPay = perksPay;
    }
    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }
    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public double getBasicPay() {
        return basicPay;
    }
    public void setBasicPay(double basicPay) {
        this.basicPay = basicPay;
    }
    public double getPerksPay() {
        return perksPay;
    }
    public void setPerksPay(double perksPay) {
        this.perksPay = perksPay;
    }
public class Organization extends Employee
{

    ArrayList<Employee> emp=new ArrayList<Employee>();
public int addEmployee(Employee e)
{
.......
}
}
```

Comment: And what's the error?

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: how do i check if the same id doesnt exist ?and then add them to the list?

Comment: You have your answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

The old java way:

```
public int addEmployee(Employee e) {
  for (Employee employee : emp) {
    if (e.getId() == employee.getId()) {
      return -1;
    }
  }
  emp.add(e);
  return emp.size();
}
```

EDIT:

The Java8 way:

```
public int addEmployee(Employee e) {
  List<Employee> alreadyInList = emp.stream().filter(em -> em.getId() == e.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
  return alreadyInList.isEmpty() ? -1 : alreadyInList.size();
}
```